# HashTable Collision Where is it using LinkedList to store multiple values which is having same keys

Tags: java, hashtable

I read many times that in a hashtable when collision arises one key with multiple values it stores in a linkedlist and then it will make equals calls to check which keys map to required value but I see code of hashtable it does not have any linkedlist code in a put method or get method. It uses Entry[] array and I dont understand how this will be used as linkedlist.

```
for (Entry<K,V> e = tab[index] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
        if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
        V old = e.value;
        e.value = value;
        return old;
        }
    }
```

Kindly guide and clear my doubt.

Comment: If you put an entry and the keys clash, the entry is overridden, no need to use any LinkedList!

Comment: @xagyg I think it is more when the keys are not the same and you don't want to lose them just because they hash to the same array index.

Comment: @Umesh It is iterating the LL. Isn't it? via e=e.next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the implementation may differ between JVM but from my understanding linked list is used (but not necessary java.util.LinkedList). This is how 'put' is implemented in HashTable in JVM I use:

```
public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
    // Make sure the value is not null
    if (value == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    // Makes sure the key is not already in the hashtable.
    HashtableEntry e;
    HashtableEntry tab[] = table;
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;

    for (e = tab[index] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
        if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
        Object old = e.value;
        e.value = value;
        return old;
        }
    }
```

There is some difference between this version and the one you posted but I think logic behind them is the same.
The HashtableEntry looks like this:

```
class HashtableEntry {
    int hash;
    Object key;
    Object value;
    HashtableEntry next;
(...)
```

the "HashtableEntry next" reference does make a HashtableEntry a linked list (a linked list is a structure in which each element has a reference to another element of the same type unless it is the last element in list). 
I think what you were looking for was java.util.LinkedList but HastTable implements linked list structure in its own way.